# Better laptop than M2 macbook air for the same price in 2022?

Tags: laptop, pc, macbook

I'm going to computer sciences studies for the next few years. I have around 1800€ (1€ = 1$) to spend in a labtop. It needs to be portable and powerful. Everyone is saying that Apple is overprice, so my question is :
Is there any thing better than the [M2 macbook air](https://www.apple.com/fr/shop/buy-mac/macbook-air/minuit-puce-apple-m2-avec-cpu-8-c%C5%93urs-et-gpu-10-c%C5%93urs-512go), with 8 Go of RAM, 512 go of storage,for about 1800€ ?
By better i mean :

- more RAM
- more performances
- bigger screen or better screen to see the most text as possible, but under 15.5 inch to stay portable.

The must have are :

- 512 Go of storage
- durable, i want to keep it for at least 5 years
- A battery that allow a full day of constant light usage
- Good portability.

By the way, do you know any software that I will use for my class that isn't compatible with the new Apple silicon chips ?
Thank you for your time, and apologies for english mistakes (i'm french).

Comment: We don't know what software you need for your class, so we have no idea regarding compatibility. Your course tutor or department head will likely have a list.

Comment: M2 is probably your worst possible choice as you can not really develop for it, being a completely closed architecture.

Comment: @peterh, I find macOS arm64 is the best development system. Your may choose Android Studio, docker arm64 or Intel, gcc, Microsoft VSCode, or Xcode. So there are not many platforms you can't develop with modern Apple arm64. Plus they generally outperform Intel laptops

Comment: @JamesRisner It is a completely closed architecture, giving you nothing more what its concurrents, but making you a slave of a single company. You know this, but you do nothing - the Apple PR is very strong and seemingly it deeply influenced your mind. Yes, I know, no one really needs multiple mouse buttons.